# r - Index of vector elements according to another vector

Tags: r, vector, matching

Assume two character, `A` and `B`:

```r
A <- c("A", "B", "B", NA, "D2", "K")
B <- c("A", "B", "C", "D1", "D2", "E", "F", "K", "L")
```

While `B` only contains unique entries, elements in `A` don't have to be unique.

Now I'd like to get the indices of the elements in `A` as they appear in `B`, except for `NA`s. Thus, in the example above, R function should return

```r
1 2 2 5 8
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 3):

We can use `match`

```
c(na.omit(match(A, B)))
#[1] 1 2 2 5 8
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another base R option using named vector

```
> na.omit(setNames(seq_along(B), B)[A])
 A  B  B D2  K
 1  2  2  5  8
attr(,"na.action")
<NA>
   4
attr(,"class")
[1] "omit"
```